# How to get User ID from slash command of another bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

**Actually I am making a Code which send user a message randomly by playing pokemeow(another bot).**

Basically, i use message content to get the userID when they use `;p` but as bots moved to slash command there is no other way left to get it...

How can I get it now?

Here is my old code i use:

````
 @commands.Cog.listener()
 async def on_message(self, message):
  user = message.author
  channel = message.channel
  
  host = self.bot.get_user(int(776865099817418793))
  channel2 = self.bot.get_channel(1009105460579807232)
  if msgcontent.startswith(";p"):
        
        def check(m):
                return m.channel == channel and m.author.id == 664508672713424926
        
                
        bot_message = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        if message.embeds:
         des = message.embeds[0].description 
         if 'wild' in des:
           print('Pokemon is spawned')
         def check(before, after):
             print('Embed edited')
         try:
          before, after = await self.bot.wait_for('message_edit', timeout=10.0)
          if after.embeds:
            des = after.embeds[0].description
            if 'You caught a' in des:
              Check = random.randint(1, 1000)
              await channel2.send(f"**{name}, Caught a Pokémon in <#{channel.id}>**\n> [ `{Check}` ]")
              if Check == 1:
                  Reward = random.choice(Grind_Rew_List)
                  em = discord.Embed(title='```py\n       Zekrom Revolution Zone         ```', color=0xF1F1F1, description=f'''**Congratulations {name} **,\n\nYou have won {Reward} by Grinding in our Server ...''')
                  em.set_footer(text="Claim your prize from Server Owner")  
                  await channel.send(f"> **{name} won Pokemeow Prize**",embed=em)
                  await host.send(f'> **{name} has won {Reward} in <#{message.channel.id}>**')
         except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          print('Time up')
````

The thing i want is to get user id when a user use `/pokemon`

[This is how their embed looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K87Cd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you got your answer but here is the code below:

For slash commands:

```
user_id = message.interaction.user.id
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks for it bro.. i already got that many time ago but as you provided correct one so I marked it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.type` to detect whether slash commands have been triggered or not.

```py
if message.type == discord.MessageType.chat_input_command:
 ...
```

You could possibly chain that with a check to see whether the message is from the bot in question or not.

[Docs on discord.MessageType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.MessageType.chat_input_command)

Comment: Bro it's fine but how i get the user ID from this?